# Is it possible to get notified (e.g. email) when the Google Play Developer Console receives a crash or ANR?

Tags: android, crash, notifications, google-play

I use [BugSnag](http://bugsnag.com) (similar to [BugSense](https://www.bugsense.com/), [Bugify](https://bugify.com/), etc.) to track and manage my Android application errors, however, I had a situation where the application crashed before BugSnag could be initialized so the only place to find this crash report was in the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) crash report.

That's fine and dandy but I had to manually check the developer console to discover that there were errors that were NOT being caught by BugSnag (they don't make it obvious, by the way).

**Is there a way to setup an email notification from the Google Play Developer Console when an error occurs?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

Google Play can send email only for `Alerts`, Not Crashes nor ANRs.

I have tried the accepted answer, and I received two crashes, but it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like you're right, @Malek. Updated to your answer as correct until this is changed by Google.

Answer (score 2):

**edit:** As Malek pointed out this approach doesn't solve the problem.

In the developer console you can go to "Settings" then "Email preferences". There should be a section "Alerts" where you can choose "I want to receive alerts for ALL of my apps".

[image: Alerts screenshot]
[image: New Alert Feature screenshot]

There weren't any crashes for my app since I changed the setting so I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: My app gets quite a few of these crashes ;) so I'll try it and see if I receive emails about it. I'll post back here with the results.

Comment: By the looks of it, this is a new feature they just added so I'm guessing this does **exactly** what we're after. Thanks for this.

Comment: Just to re-visit my old comment, this doesn't do **exactly** what we're after. Crashes are not included in these alerts, unfortunately.