# Auto notification when Android app gets report for ANR or Crash

Tags: android

Is there a way to configure the Google Developer Console to send me an email whenever it receives a report for a Crash or an ANR?

I've found this question: 
[Is it possible to get notified (e.g. email) when the Google Play Developer Console receives a crash or ANR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619604/is-it-possible-to-get-notified-e-g-email-when-the-google-play-developer-conso)

Which is not answered, and I think this is something that should be possible.

Anyone knows how?

Comment: There is no way. Use http://acra.ch/ for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a service like bugsense https://www.bugsense.com/ which will email you and give you nice other features.  There are paid and free accounts

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ACRA** lib. which is very helpful for reporting any crash in your application and also send error reports even if the application doesn't crash
, you can also hide the ANR window with some of your predefined Text/msg.

for more info : [https://github.com/ACRA/acra]